# Prove convergence for: $\sum^{\infty}_{x=0} \frac{7x^2 + 4}{9^x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I prove that this sum converges:

$\sum^{\infty}_{x=0} \frac{7x^2 + 4}{9^x}$.

The hint says to use the fact that $7x^2 + 4 < 2^x$ whenever $x > 10  $.

Not sure how to use this info.

Answer (score 2):

There is more than one way to do this but the hint certainly makes things short. Note that $\sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{7x^2+4}{9^x}$ converges if and only if $\sum_{x=11}^\infty \frac{7x^2+4}{9^x}$ converges (after all, those first few terms shouldn't make a difference!). But then
$$
0 \leq \sum_{x=11}^\infty \frac{7x^2+4}{9^x} \leq \sum_{x=11}^\infty \dfrac{2^x}{9^x}
$$
Can you see why this is true? Now can you rewrite the series on the right into a type of series that you know? Specifically, a type of series so special that you know when it converges/diverges (and can even find the sum if it converges!). After this, why can you say that your series converges?

Comment: your index in the last series is n---)

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Ah yes, thank you! I am so adjusted to using this index that using $x$ (especially when one reserves this for power series) just seems unnatural!

Comment: Yeah, it is so unusual.